# wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized from BusyBox

Tags: curl, wget, busybox

*I know that Axis camera API specific issue should be raised at axis developer community forum but the issue seems generic to http web access so trying to get some help here*

I have Axis IP camera connected to local network. I am facing issue in accessing Camera API through wget/curl commands from BusyBox (Embedded Board in same local network)

When accessing Camera through its API from window cygwin's wget command, its giving me valid response:

```
admin@LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/axis $ wget -O imageformat.txt 'http://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=Properties.Image.Format'
    --2021-06-30 11:13:07--  http://root:*password*@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=Properties.Image.Format
    Connecting to 192.168.0.90:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
    Authentication selected: Digest realm="AXIS_ACCC8E6E45B0", nonce="XTNm1/7FBQA=2e3d1152262381d33e3cf6abe6c728db4921c928", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
    Reusing existing connection to 192.168.0.90:80.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: unspecified [text/plain]
    Saving to: ‘imageformat.txt’
    
    imageformat.txt      [ <=>       ]      47  --.-KB/s    in 0s
    
    2021-06-30 11:13:07 (470 KB/s) - ‘imageformat.txt’ saved [47]
```

But when I try to achieve the same from wget/curl command from BusyBox shell its failing with 'error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized' I am sure that camera credentials (username/password) are correct (as I am able to access the camera from browser and windows cygwin shell with same credentials):

```
root@admin:~# curl 'http://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=Properties.Image.Format'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>

root@mainboard-sbs:~# wget -O imageformat.txt 'http://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/param.cgi?action=list&group=Properties.Image.Format'
Connecting to 192.168.0.90 (192.168.0.90:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

What can be the issue? Am I missing any authentication/certificate parameters from busybox's wget?

```
Version on windows machine:
admin@LAPTOP /cygdrive/c/axis $ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.21.1 built on cygwin.

Version on busybox machine:
root@admin:~# wget
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2019-02-19 13:37:55 IST) multi-call binary.
```

Comment: Trying passing the credentials to curl using the `-u user:pass` option/argument instead of as part of the URL.

Comment: @jesse_b tried and that didn't helped shows same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm posting answer to my own query if it can help someone someday...

wget(v1.18) came with busybox(v1.24.1) was not full featured wget and it was installed with minimal switches so updating wget recipe to v1.21.1 resolved the issue.